# How do I re-export an imported module that has interfaces in it in a usable manner?

Tags: typescript

I had one file with a large number of modules in it. I wanted to separate those modules into different files and expose them from the original file. This is because the original file is >800 loc and becoming very difficult to manage.

So I have created a file that contains a module with functions and interfaces:

```js
export module Subsection1 {
    
    export interface Interface {
        id: string;
    }
    
    export function DoInterfaceStuff(obj: any) {
        return = <Interface>{ id: obj }
    }
}
```

I have the

```js
import { Subsection1 as Subsection1Base } from "./Subsection1";


export module GodManager {

    export type Subsection1 = Subsection1Base & (typeof Subsection1Base);
    export var Subsection1 = Subsection1Base;

    var ObjByID = new Map<string, Subsection1.Interface>();
    export function DoThing(source) {
        ObjByID.set(source.id, Subsection1.DoInterfaceStuff(source.origin));
    }
}
```

**NOTE**
The new name and variable *must* be accessible externally to the current class because I'm actually loading Subsection1Base lazily (mostly to avoid a circular dependancy).

Comment: Why do you call both the interface and the module (namespace) `Trigger`? You could call the interface `ITrigger` instead. Or you could put the Trigger interface into the Trigger module.

Comment: I use this pattern a lot for typescript, mostly to get static methods and members out of classes to clean up the code. The fact that it is an interface this time is uncommon and I found out later actually likely not related to the real issue. I believe the problem occurs just with any interface that's defined within a module if the module is reexported (it loses the internal interface's typing information).

Comment: Looks like there's already a feature request in typescript for exactly this functionality:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4336

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @Connor Low pointed me in the right direction by highlighting the right error, but this is the actual solution to the question.

From [this github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4529) Imported modules from other files can be reexported using the `import export Name = Value` syntax.

So rewriting the example code, the solution is:

```js
import { Subsection1 as Subsection1Base } from "./Subsection1";


export module GodManager {

    export import Subsection1 = Subsection1Base;

    var ObjByID = new Map<string, Subsection1.Interface>();
    export function DoThing(source) {
        ObjByID.set(source.id, Subsection1.DoInterfaceStuff(source.origin));
    }
}
```

And it all works!

Answer (score 1):

#### Prelude

The question changed the example code but they originally had exported a `module`
and `interface` with the same name and tried to reference the `module` in a context where only the `interface` was valid. While it is not necessarily incorrect to share a name between two different declarations of separate language constructs, it did obscure the true issue they were experiencing (see original answer below).

#### Original Answer

If we clean up the naming of your types, we can figure out pretty quickly what's wrong here.

In TriggerEvent, we rename the interface `Trigger` to `ITrigger`:

```
export interface ITrigger {
    // ..
}

export module Trigger {
    //...
    
    export function Serialise(restoredEvent: ITrigger) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Now, in `ActionManager`, we can see what went wrong:

```
import { Trigger as TriggerBase } from "./TriggerEvent";

export module ActionManager {

    type Trigger = TriggerBase & (typeof Trigger); 
    //             ^^^^^^^^^^^
    // ERROR - Cannot use namespace 'TriggerBase' as a type.
    var Trigger = TriggerBase;

    var EventsByID = new Map<UUID, Trigger>();
    var PrepreparedInputs = new Map<UUID, Trigger.Serialised>(); 
    //                                    ^^^^^^^ 
    // ERROR - 'Trigger' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.
}
```

**You cannot use a namespace (module) as a type.** (see [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#basic-concepts)). Before, since the interface and the module were named the same, TypeScript went with the context-appropriate option, the interface. Ergo, no errors there! Regardless, we still have the original error `'Trigger' only refers to a type...` because a type is a type, and not a namespace (or module).

Finally, `ActionManager.Trigger.Serialise(stuff);` isn't working because Trigger isn't exported from the ActionManager module.

#### Solution

Since you can't assign a `module` to a `type`, reference the module directly in your `PreparedInputs`:

```
    var PrepreparedInputs = new Map<UUID, TriggerBase.Serialised>();
```

And, as you did with `TriggerEvent`, export what types/variables you want to use outside a module:

```
// The interface was renamed to ITrigger in TriggerEvent.
import { Trigger as TriggerBase, ITrigger } from "./TriggerEvent"; 

export module ActionManager {
    export var Trigger = TriggerBase;

    export var EventsByID = new Map<UUID, ITrigger>();
    export var PrepreparedInputs = new Map<UUID, TriggerBase.Serialised>(); 
}
```

Comment: Offtopic rant: Splitting static functionality into a module class that's named the same as the class itself is not going drive everyone nuts. You just don't like it. This pattern is quite similar to how C++ splits definitions into a separate file, and I don't see anyone complaining about that. Everything is still in the same file and F12 in every editor still finds the right function, it just makes it much easier to navigate within the file.

Comment: I don't know about c++ definition splitting (is that anything like c# partial classes?), but a `module` is a completely different type of thing than an `interface`, which is what led to the asker's issue in the first place (they thought they were including a module but it was actually the interface). I'm sure there is more nuance than either of us is divulging.

Comment: Nothing like. In C++ all definitions for classes (variable signatures, method signatures, public and protected modifiers) have to be specified in a .h file and the contents go in a .cpp file. This was also the case in C. My comment was in reply to you saying it would drive everyone nuts, it seems clear you don't have much experience with many different programming languages so I recommend you give C++ a try sometime. It's a great language. Related: the compile error being wrong is just a bug in the compiler, merging interfaces is in their docs so it's supported. Also I'm the original asker.

Comment: Very well, I updated my answer. I still think it is best to distinguish (via unique naming) modules from interfaces since they are completely different things in typescript, but I was too broad with my statement.